# Trying to parse numbers with regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to parse all numbers from a text:

```
text 2030 text 2,5 text 2.000.000 2,000,000 -200 +31600000000. 200. 2.5 200? 1:200
```

Based on this regex:

```php
(?<!\S)(\-?|\+?)(\d*\.?\,?\d+|\d{1,3}(,?.?\d{3})*(\.\,\d+)?)(?!\S)
```

But endings like `.`, `?`, `!`, `,` right after the number doesn't match. I only want full matches with `preg_match_all`. (see image)

[image: Overview of matches]

I guess that the problem is in the last part of my regex `(?!\S)`. I tried different things but I can't figured it out how to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we don't wish to validate our numbers, maybe we could then start with a simple expression, maybe something similar to:

```
(?:^|\s)([+-]?[\d:.,]*\d)\b
```

#### Test

```
$re = '/(?:^|\s)([+-]?[\d:.,]*\d)\b/s';
$str = 'text 2030 text 2,5 text 2.000.000 2,000,000 -200 +31600000000. 200. 2.5 200? 1:200
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

In the right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/FKQrr5/1/), the expression is further explained, if you might be interested.

---

EDITS:

Another expression would be:

```
(?:^|\s)\K[+-]?(?:\d+:\d+|\d+(?:[.,]\d{1,3})+|\d+)\b
```

which would not still validate our numbers and just collect those listed, with some invalid numbers.

#### [DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/h9rde8/1/)

#### [DEMO 3](https://regex101.com/r/VxveTX/1/)

Comment: Note that with your last edit with `\b` numbers with (prefix minus or plus) -123 and +123 not get grouped in the match

Comment: This is awesome! My test case didn't contain this scenario `,,,,1` you did self added this thank you for that, but is there an easy fix for that? #sorry